# Background Scaling for different Mobile aspect ratios. Unity 2D / C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mobile

I recently started using Unity and C# and am currently working on a Vertical 2D mobile Game. I'm struggling to get my background to scale with different aspect ratios. The background sprite is 19,5/9 and the playable area is 16/9. At the moment the background is scaling to fit the top and bottom of the screen, but the idea is to have the background anchored to the sides and bottom and for the view to extend upwards if needed (Hence the tall sprite). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.
Here is the code im trying, its attached to the Camera.

```
public SpriteRenderer background;

private void Start()
{
     float screenRatio = (float)Screen.width / (float)Screen.height;
    float targetRatio = background.bounds.size.x / background.bounds.size.y;

    if(screenRatio >= targetRatio)
    {
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = background.bounds.size.y / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        float differenceInSize = targetRatio / screenRatio;
        Camera.main.orthographicSize = background.bounds.size.y / 2 * differenceInSize;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use a worldspace UI canvas.

Set the canvas to world space, place it at the desired depth in your scene (dimensions won't matter as we can set them in the script), and either add an image object as a child or add an image component to the canvas object. Add your sprite as the source for the image like so.

```
void Awake()
{

    RectTransform rt = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    rt.position = new Vector3(0, 0, rt.position.z);
    float camHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize * 2;
    rt.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Vertical, camHeight);
    float targetRectWidth = camHeight * Camera.main.aspect;
    rt.SetSizeWithCurrentAnchors(RectTransform.Axis.Horizontal, targetRectWidth);
    
}
```

The Steps are:

- sets the rect transform to be positioned in the centre of the screen at whatever depth you set it at in the editor.
- get 2xCamera height (as that is the distance from the top to bottom of the screen)
- sets the anchors so that it lines the UI object up with the top and bottom of the screen
- gets the target width by multiplying the height by the aspect ratio of the camera
- sets the correct width based the target width

This can be done in update instead of Awake or Start to dynamically size the background while playing if necessary.

Here it is at 1080p 16:9 and at 5:4.The red cube is to show that it is in the background behind objects in the scene.

[image: At 1020p 16:9]

[image: At 5:4 aspect ratio]